# GroovyShell: embedded execution

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I'm trying to embed groovy into a large Java application.

The Java application should load some utility Groovy scripts at startup.

The application should then run other scripts multiple times.  There is also a need to enter some code at a GUI and execute it at user request.

The problem I'm facing is this:

I am loading the startup script like this:

```
GroovyShell gShell = new GroovyShell();
gShell.evaluate(new FileReader("scripts/autoload.groovy"));
```

Suppose my autoload.groovy contains:

```
def prnt(m) {
    println("From Groovy: " + m);
}
```

This works fine.  But when I want to run a user command using:

```
gShell.evaluate("prnt 66");
```

I get the error:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script2.prnt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [66]`

How can my user script access the methods already loaded?

Note:  I have also tried "autoload.prnt 88", and still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `evaluate` call is compiled and run as a separate `Script`, and

```
def prnt(m) {
    println("From Groovy: " + m);
}
```

defines a method in the Script class generated from `autoload.groovy`, which is not accessible from the subsequent "calling" script.  However, the scripts run by the same `GroovyShell` share the same *binding*, so you can store values in the binding from one script and access them in another.  Storing a value in the binding is simply a case of assigning the value to an otherwise undeclared variable:

```
prnt = { m ->
    println("From Groovy: " + m);
}
```

This stores a closure in the binding variable `prnt`, and you can call the closure from other scripts in the same shell.  Note that

```
def prnt = { m ->
```

or

```
Closure prnt = { m ->
```

would *not* work, because the `def` or type makes it a local variable declaration (private to this particular script) rather than an assignment to the binding.